# Azure Table Storage Querying using Python- Read Integer Column

Tags: python, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am trying to query Azure Table Storage using Python. An int32 datatype column doesn't return its value but returns something like this **azure.storage.table.models.EntityProperty obj....**. But, in case of string datatype columns, i am not facing any such issues. Could someone please help me ?

The column Pos in below script is an integer column in the table

```
queryfilter = "startDateTime gt datetime'%s' and temp eq '%s'" % (datefilter, temp)

task = table_service.query_entities(azureTable, filter=queryfilter)

for t in task: 
   print(t.Pos)
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Hi Sraw, script added

Comment: You could modify `azureTable` to `'azureTable'`,then have a try.

Comment: Hi Joy, the above script works for all other columns of string type from azureTable except the column Pos of int datatype. azureTable is a parameter passed while querying. I changed it with quotes but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.cosmosdb.table.models.entityproperty?view=azure-python, can you try the following?

```
for t in task: print(t.Pos.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Azure Table Storage has a new python library in preview release that is available for installation via pip. To install use the following pip command

```
pip install azure-data-tables
```

This SDK is able to target either a Tables or Cosmos endpoint (albeit there are known issues with Cosmos).

The new library uses a similar `TableEntity` which is a key-value type inheriting from the Python dictionary, the value is the same `EntityProperty`. There are two ways to access entity properties. If the type is an `Int32` (default integer type) or `String` they can be accessed by:

```py
my_value = entity.my_key  # direct access
my_value = entity['my_key'] # same access pattern as a dict
```

If the `EntityProperty` is of type `INT32` or `BINARY` then you will have to use the `.value` notation:

```py
my_value = entity.my_key.value  # direct access
my_value = entity['my_key'].value # same access pattern as a dict
```

FYI I am a full-time engineer at Microsoft on the Azure SDK for Python team.